Android App Widget with multiple mapping views ignores partial updates
I have an app with a Home screen widget, created with the RemoteViews(Map<SizeF, RemoteViews>) constructor, so the choice of layout to inflate depends on the widget size. The map has 2 views. This part works OK, but I also need to perform partial updates of this widget using AppWidgetManager#partiallyUpdateAppWidget(), and this seems to always be ignored.
It does work when I used a single, non-mapped RemoteViews instance however. I suspect the issue is due to the requirement of partiallyUpdateAppWidget() that:

This method will be ignored if a widget has not received a full update via AppWidgetManager#updateAppWidget(int[], RemoteViews)

Presumably the "mapping" RemoteViews gets the update but not the layout it inflates, so the layout that partiallyUpdateAppWidget() tries to update isn't flagged as having been updated, so it is ignored.
Has anyone else encountered this, or found a solution?

A googler said:

The current behavior is working as intended. partialUpdate is not
intended to be used for merging tree structure. In those cases, its
safer to just push the full remoteViews, instead of keeping track to
what sizes were pushed in the previous update (as the sizes could also
have changed by then)

https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/3370144/comments/3206c3d3_c34e247a
It appears to be an undocumented works-as-intended limitation.
